# How to find multiple underscore in the same string?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have strings with different numbers of underscores. I am trying to select the strings that contain two or more underscores. Any suggestions?

```
Strings <- c("aa_bb", "aa_bb_cc_dd", "jah_ghtfv_jal")
```

Currently I have:

```
Match1 <- Strings[grepl("[_].+[_]", Strings) == TRUE,] and
Match2 <- Strings[grepl("_.*_", Strings) == TRUE,]
```

Both return slightly different counts.  Can anyone come up with a better way to count to return strings that have two or more underscores?

In this case I would like to return "aa_bb_cc_dd, "jah_ghtfv_jal".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the strings can take any form and the underscores can appear anywhere (including, for example, just two underscores "__"), you could just count them using `stringr::str_count`:

```
library(stringr)
Strings[str_count(Strings, "_") > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current use of `grepl` is incorrect, and you should be using this:

```
Match1 <- Strings[grepl("[_].+[_]", Strings)]
Match2 <- Strings[grepl("_.*_", Strings)]
```

Both of these return identical results, in line with what you expect.  But, I think what you really here is:

```
Strings <- c("aa_bb", "aa_bb_cc_dd", "jah_ghtfv_jal")
Strings[grepl("_[^_]+_", Strings)]

[1] "aa_bb_cc_dd"   "jah_ghtfv_jal"
```

This matches any string which has an underscore, followed by one or more non underscore characters, followed by a second underscore.